# Kali Linux won't run in full screen

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I'm running Kali linux in VirtualBox and it couldn't find any network adapters or `wlan0`. So, I followed some instructions I found about downgrading to `compat-wireless-2010-06-26.p.tar.bz2` and it temporarily fixed the `wlan0` problem, but still wouldn't find any wireless networks. (Apparently it can't find the built in wireless adapter from inside VirtualBox.)

However, if you close Kali and reboot you end up in the same position of having to load and unload the file. So I decided to update Kali back to where it was (`sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`). After I ran that and it updated, I rebooted.

But now it won't run in full screen. I had this same problem when I first downloaded it and never found a fix - it randomly worked itself out.

I've entered the repositories and ran `sh ./VBoxLinuxAddition.run` and it will build the kernel modules and everything, but even after reboot it still runs in small screen mode. When I boot up it will say `A start job is running for vboxadd.service` and after I log in to root it will say `VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel service is not running.`

nano sources.list

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

`deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf3-HnC1KyA

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a few separate issues here. Re: the adapter settings, one option is to try setting the Network Settings for the Virtual machine to 'Bridged adapter'. You can then select one of the choices from the drop-down box entitled 'Name'. You would then select 'wired connection' in the top right-hand corner of Kali.

I would also update Virtualbox. 
If you've got a recent edition of Kali you should only have had to issue the following commands when your internet was up and running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
reboot
```

When you say, 'I've entered the repositories and ran "sh ./VBoxLinuxAddition.run"' did you click on "Insert Guest Additions CD image" from the 'Devices' menu in Virtualbox and copy the file from there?

I have found that when the first option doesn't work, the Guest Additions CD from the Virtualbox menu normally does the trick. The full instructions for this is the second installation option on the [Kali web-site](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest)

I have found that the Guest Additions can be a problem with Kali. Sometimes it's easier and quicker to back up your important files, delete the Virtual Machine, along with the Kali folder inside the VMs folder on your hard-drive and create a new one, with an up-to-date `.iso`, to avoid head-aches.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked like this (I was running it in a VM on Debian 8):

- Get the latest **virtualbox-guest-x11**
- When you first start the machine (or whenever) **logout** with an **unsaved
  session** and you will have the **fullscreen** in lockscreen and on your
  desktop after you login. (Make sure you logout, otherwise tweek the
  options in XFCE desktop startup scripts or display settings.)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me:

After inserting the guest CD and running the `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` you would get all the necessary installed but even after that small screen problem pursue. Then try to go the virtual box main bar click view->auto resize to guest display.

This works for me and I hope this works for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This method works as of  September 2019.

1. Click on **power icon** and select **Settings**.

[image]

2. In **Settings**, go to **devices -> displays**. Click on **Resolution** and select appropriate one for your display.

[image]

3. Then a dialog box will appear asking whether we want to keep the new resolution? Agree to that.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf3-HnC1KyA&start=23

Answer (score 0):

Okay!! So I tried to find a solution to this issue and all I got was just this same answer over and over on every site I looked in. I did have the same issue, but actually my issue started after I did the 'apt upgrade', not sure if the upgrade modified some of my display files or something similar. As I'm a new user on Kali so have no clue about what files control the display settings.

ISSUE :

- I'm running kali-linux-2020.3-vbox-amd64, this was a fresh install and ran apt upgrade
  after which I was not able to access the machine in full screen mode.
- I was able to run the VM in full screen mode before the upgrade.
- After the upgrade I can change my Display settings in Kali but none of the display
  settings worked for me.

WORKAROUND:
Switch to the Scaled Mode in your VM View option.
Once in the Scaled Mode, change the Display settings from the Kali Settings and change the resolution to something that suits you.(For me 1440x900 worked fine!)

I know this is not the best solution but still hope this helps!!